# How does ElasticSearch calculate memory pressure?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

We have a couple of Java services that we would like to add monitoring/alarms to.

We were collecting memory usage information from the JVM. Then, we noticed that ElasticSearch has a metric called memory pressure which sounds like a useful metric for our Java services as well.

The problem is that I can't figure out how it works. I've tried searching for "memory pressure" in the code on their [GitHub](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch), to no avail.

When I try to search for the formula or an explanation of how it calculates this, I somehow always end up finding the same two articles: [Understanding the Memory Pressure Indicator](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-understanding-memory-pressure-indicator/) and [JVM memory pressure indicator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-memory-pressure.html).

Those nicely explain how to *interpret* the values ElasticSearch calculates, but not *how* it calculates it.

Does anyone know how the ElasticSearch memory pressure calculation works under the hood?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned on the third link you referenced:

> the JVM memory pressure indicator is actually the **fill rate of the old generation pool**

So it's simply the percentage of the old pool usage

When retrieving the `GET _nodes/stats` you'll get the following information regarding the JVM metrics:

```
  ...
  "jvm" : {
    "timestamp" : 1614957874986,
    "uptime_in_millis" : 274397434,
    "mem" : {
      "heap_used_in_bytes" : 20094897664,
      "heap_used_percent" : 65,
      "heap_committed_in_bytes" : 30836523008,
      "heap_max_in_bytes" : 30836523008,
      "non_heap_used_in_bytes" : 310525488,
      "non_heap_committed_in_bytes" : 321077248,
      "pools" : {
        "young" : {
          "used_in_bytes" : 6710886400,
          "max_in_bytes" : 0,
          "peak_used_in_bytes" : 12264144896,
          "peak_max_in_bytes" : 0
        },
        "old" : {
          "used_in_bytes" : 13098798592,
          "max_in_bytes" : 30836523008,
          "peak_used_in_bytes" : 14881037312,
          "peak_max_in_bytes" : 30836523008
        },
        "survivor" : {
          "used_in_bytes" : 285212672,
          "max_in_bytes" : 0,
          "peak_used_in_bytes" : 1300234240,
          "peak_max_in_bytes" : 0
        }
      }
    },
```

So the memory pressure is simply computed with the following formula:

```
100 * jvm.mem.pools.old.used_in_bytes / jvm.mem.pools.old.max_in_bytes
```

Which in my case yields 42% and can be seen on the following screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation!
Must have been to close to the weekend or something that I read over that part for 3 times or so!